# How to parse a file in PHP

Tags: php, parsing, file

I have a string with the following content

```
 [text1] some content [text2] some
 content some content [text3] some
 content
```

The "[textn]" are finite and also have specific names. I want to get the content into an array. Any idea?

Comment: Can you give some real world examples? Is it an option to modify the data format to make it work with an existing parsing library, e.g. XML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In php there are function for splitting the string with regexp delimiters, like preg_match, preg_match_all, look them up.

If you have a word list, you can split the string like this (obviously, one could write it much nicer):

```
$words = array('[text1]','[text2]','[text3]');
$str = "[text1] some content [text2] some content some content [text3] some content3";

for ($i=0; $i<sizeof($words) ; $i++) { 
  $olddel = $del;
  $del = $words[$i];
  list($match,$str) = explode($del,$str);
  if ($i-1 >= 0) {  $matches[$i-1] = $olddel.' '.$match; }
}
$matches[] =$del." ".$str;

print_r($matches);
```

This will output: `Array ( [0] => [text1] some content [1] => [text2] some content some content [2] => [text3] some content3 )`

Answer (score 3):

If you don't wanna use regular expressions, then [strtok()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtok.php) would do the trick here:

```
strtok($txt, "[");      // search for first [

while ($id = strtok("]")) {   // alternate ] and [
    $result[$id] = strtok("[");   // add token
}
```

Comment: Note that this will fail on nested `[]`, e.g. `[foo [bar]]`. For this case, you'll need to use a text parser.

Comment: @marcog: I think you are assuming it's BBcode. OPs example looks more like an ini file. (Where my example behaves as simple-minded/dumb as parse_ini_file.)

Comment: @marcog, he can use preg match all with complicated patterns like /\{((?>[^{}]+)|(?R))*\}/ but...

Comment: I'm not assuming anything. @Webarto Yes, but...what about `[foo\]bar]`?

Answer (score 1):

preg_match or preg_match_all, you need to give us an example if you want regex.

```
$string = "[text1] some content [text2] some content some content [text3] some content";

preg_match_all("#\[([^\[\]]+)\]#is", $string, $matches);

print_r($matches); //Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => [text1] [1] => [text2] [2] => [text3] ) [1] => Array ( [0] => text1 [1] => text2 [2] => text3 ) )
```

Non-recursive.

Comment: It works, however, the content can have [] inside it; so it breaks. Luckily text1, text2... are finite and I know them beforehand, so I went with Zoltan solution; thank you for your input :)

Answer (score 0):

Is [ and ] part of the string or did you just use them to highlight the part that you want to extract? If it is not, then you can use

```
if (preg_match_all("/\b(text1|text2|text3|foo|bar)\b/i", $string, $matches)) {
   print_r($matches);
}
```